# Error: expected expression, got '.' in Optional chaining (?.)

Tags: javascript

I want to use optional chaining in javascript. I saw this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```
const adventurer = {
  name: 'Alice',
  cat: {
    name: 'Dinah'
  }
};

let dogName = adventurer.dog?.name;
console.log(dogName);
```

According to the documentation, I should get a result equivalent to **undefined**; But I get below error:

```
Error: expected expression, got '.'
```

I searched and checked the other answers, but the problem was not solved.

Comment: Optional chaining is pretty new. [Not all browsers/versions support it](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining). [Use a transpiler](https://babeljs.io/) if you want to use it but still want to support older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks good and works well in javscript *V8 8.5.210.26*

Which version you run script?

how about check specifications that node or binary support it.

Comment: I use firefox 68.5.0esr (64-bit). It's true, this version not support optional chaining.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Yes it is a comment but the problem is on supporting by engine *version*. there is no details about version used on the question. I can answer like this at all.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into the documentation and the only explanation I can see for that not work is the browser.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tested and worked on latest chrome and node 14.

Please make sure you are using browser/node version which supports it, there is more info on the [same page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#Browser_compatibility)